# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf - correct context path handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm developing web application using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. What is the correct way to make links of pages work regardless of where the application deployed? For example, if I write

```
<a href="/about">Link</a>
```

and deploy my application not to `/`, but in `/app/`, link will not work.

I thought about getting current path in every Controller method like this: `request.getContextPath()` and than using it in every link on the page, but maybe there is a way to do it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Thymeleaf, you should be able to use `<a th:href="@{/about}">Link</a>` assuming that `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">` has been declared. I think this does require using `SpringTemplateEngine`.